# SP2016 "About me" link does not work

Tags: my-site, 2016, my

We migrated from `SP2013` to `SP2016`.

The link "About me" in the top right corner points to `http://portal/Person.aspx`, by clicking it the system tells `Page not found`.

I took a look in the `Central Administration` -> `My Site Settings` where followings are defined:

`My Site Host` -> `http://portal:80/my/`
`Personal Site Location` -> `my/personal`

What to do to solve this issue?

The curious thing is that using a static link `http://portal/my/Person.aspx?accountname=i:0#.w|domain\username` the page opens for all users, except the current one.

Why?

Same behaviour when accessing `http://portal/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=A_USER_ID`. It works except for the current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After years I have been able to fix it. The `Trusted Host Location` was missing. To fix it go to the Central Administration -> User Profile Service -> Configure Trusted Host Locations and add http://yourPortal/my where my is the `Personal Site Location` configured under Setup My Sites

Answer (score 0):

Please check and confirm the following:

1. "About me" url is "`http://portal/Person.aspx`". Is it a typo or is this correct?
2. What was the url of mysite host in SP2013?
3. Does a user who did not have mysite earlier face similar issue?
4. Does a user which was added in SP 2016 directly also face same issue?
5. What is the value of Personal Site Url for the user. User profile Service Application > Manage User profile > Search for User Profile > Edit Profile > check value of "Personal Site" Field. if it is / change it to /my/personal/ and validate "About Me" again.

Comment: 1) It's correct. Why do you think it is a typo? 2) On 2013 we had an alternative intranet access wich pointed to the same url. 3) All users have/had a personal site. 4) No new user in 2016. 5) It is /my/personal/{username}/